# Xcode iOS barcode scanner in background mode using Apple Vision framework

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, barcode-scanner, apple-vision

I'm looking to see if it's possible to build iOS barcode scanner with Apples vision framework (Xcode, swift). I know how to build a barcode scanner when view controller is active, However I'm looking to see if somehow its possible to scan without a view controller being active (Whenever a barcode is placed infront of camera, it becomes active).

I couldn't find anything on internet so looking to see if its even possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: I’m certain that you _can’t_ access the camera while your app is in the background. I thing this doesn’t even work for VoIP apps like FaceTime.

Comment: No i didn't mean if my whole app is in background. I meant a view controller where where I 'm access camera, if that is in background. Lets say I'm at "home" viewController and someone puts a barcode infront of camera, I want to segue to my "camera" viewController from "home" view controller. I hope im making sense.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel any help would be appreciated!